# Reflection: Invoke method, passing a delegate as parameter

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an interface implemented in `Host` class that looks like this:

```
void Method1(Action<Args1> action1, Action<Args1> action2);
```

and then I have the following methods to be passed for `action1` and `action2`.

```
private void Action1(Args1 obj)
{
//...
}

private void Action2(Args1 obj)
{
//...
}
```

Using reflection, how do I invoke it with and pass methods `Action1` and `Action2`?

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection to accomplish this? Also which types are `Action1` and `Action2` declared in?

Comment: @Ani I use reflection so my plugin will be backward-compatible; it will not execute Method1 if it can't be reflected from base assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//here you pass the methods Action1 and Action2 as parameters
//to the delegates - if you need to construct these by reflection
//then you need to reflect the methods and use the
//Delegate.CreateDelegate method.
var param1 = new Action<Args1>(Action1);
var param2 = new Action<Args1>(Action2);
//instance of Host on which to execute
var hostInstance = new Host();
var method = typeof(Host).GetMethod("Method1", 
  BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

method.Invoke(hostInstance, new object[] { param1, param2 });
```